# Message: Undefined property: Error in codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigntier rest api to generate token,and on my localhost it is working fine and after upload,it is not working.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Authorization_Token');
}
```

My controller function,I called like these:

```
$payload = ['id' => $uids];
$token = $this->Authorization_Token->generateToken($payload);
```

The error I got from server.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>   Message:  Undefined property: User_Api::$Authorization_Token
>   Filename: controllers/User_api.php
>   Line Number: 164

please help me how to solve it..
note: the capital letters are correct.

Comment: Have you double checked that you uploaded all files?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes.. checked ..

Comment: is there any server config??

Comment: Did you upload Authorization_Token library?

Comment: yes..now working if i remove caps.. $token = $this->authorization_Token->generateToken($payload); don't know why..but working..

Comment: You can try with load library like `$this->load->library('authorization_token');`

Comment: // Load Authorization Token Library
$this->load->library('Authorization_Token');
// and use this library like this
$this->authorization_token->generateToken($token_data);